# download link for asp not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, file-upload

I am using the download link for my upload and download method in my ASP.NET Project. i created a database with fields

`tFileName (nvarchar 100) , tFileupload (nvarchar 100), tFileData (varbinary (max))`.

The data saves when I upload it and the fields are being saved. My problem is I can't seem to download the data from the database.

ill be posting my code and my c# codes. hope someone can help me. thanks!

My asp.net code, this code is inside my `UpdatePanel` also.

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvFile" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" HeaderStyle-BackColor="#3AC0F2" HeaderStyle-ForeColor="White"
                                RowStyle-BackColor="#A1DCF2" AlternatingRowStyle-BackColor="White" AlternatingRowStyle-ForeColor="#000" CellPadding="5">
                                    <Columns>
                                        <asp:BoundField DataField="tFileName" HeaderText="File Name" />
                                        <asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
                                            <ItemTemplate>
                                                <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkDownload" runat="server" Text="Download" OnClick="lnkDownload_Click" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("TravelNumber") %>'></asp:LinkButton>
                                            </ItemTemplate>
                                        </asp:TemplateField>
                                    </Columns>
                                </asp:GridView>
```

And here is my code for my `aspx.cs`

```
public void getFile()
{
    Utility u = new Utility();
    string conn = u.local();
    using (SqlConnection connUser = new SqlConnection(conn))
    {
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
        {
            cmd.CommandText = "select TravelNumber, tFileName from TravelTransaction";
            cmd.Connection = connUser;
            connUser.Open();
            gvFile.DataSource = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            gvFile.DataBind();
            connUser.Close();
        }
    }
}

protected void lnkDownload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int id = int.Parse((sender as LinkButton).CommandArgument);
    byte[] bytes;
    string fileName, contentType;
    Utility u = new Utility();
    string conn = u.local();
    using (SqlConnection connUser = new SqlConnection(conn))
    {
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
        {
            cmd.CommandText = "select tFileName, tFileUpload, tFileData from TravelTransaction where TravelNumber = @Trav";
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Trav", id));
            cmd.Connection = connUser;
            connUser.Open();
            using (SqlDataReader sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                sdr.Read();
                bytes = (byte[])sdr["tFileData"];
                contentType = sdr["tFileUpload"].ToString();
                fileName = sdr["tFileName"].ToString();
            }
            connUser.Close();
        }
    }
    Response.Clear();
    Response.Buffer = true;
    Response.Charset = "";
    Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
    Response.ContentType = contentType;
    Response.AppendHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=" + fileName);
    Response.BinaryWrite(bytes);
    Response.Flush();
    Response.End();
}
```

I can't seem to find my error, actually there is no errors in it. But the file does not download and no action are happening. What is wrong with my code?

Comment: you didn't specified of where to download/save the file... there's nothing wrong with your code in converting the varbinary to byte but you didn't write the code using any StreamWrite to save the file

Comment: for short, your code is incomplete..

Comment: how can i use the streamwrite? thanks!

Comment: @JCBorlagdan This is a webpage, and the browser will download the data through the HTTP connection, StreamWrite is not needed. The code comes almost literally from http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Upload-and-Download-files-from-SQL-Server-Database-in-ASPNet.aspx and seems okay.

Comment: Just one thing: in case the fileName contains spaces, it is wise to surround it with double quotes so `"attachment;filename=\"" + fileName + "\""`, otherwise some browsers may choke.